# SMD Capacitor - read its values - 3H5 VLPU 330 2.5v

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

I have to replace a capacitor from a motherboard, but I can't find any information about the manufacturer, capacitance, voltage, tolerance and ESR values.

I suppose the capacitance is: 330uF (not sure, because I've found online that the coloured band can indicate the multiplier 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1,...) and voltage: 2.5v, but nothing about manufacturer, tolerance and ESR.

Here the image (3H5 VLPU 330 2.5v)
[image]

Can you help me please?

Thanks,

Alessandro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Possible substitute in stock

  - 1st is  16 mOhm ESR vs original 12mOhm
  - 2nd is 10 mOhm ESR
    Aluminum Polymer low profile low ESR 330uF 2.5V

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nichicon/RSL0E331MCN1GB/493-3817-1-ND/2239372

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/2R5SVPE330MY/P16533CT-ND/4204340

I would go with 2)

in future Lookup 330uF 2.5V and check photos and compare specs. and [X] in stock and cut tape for SMD (1pc)

Answer (score 2):

It is a polymer cap by Matsuki Polimer. Datasheet can be found [here](http://www.fce.com.tw/images/polymer_smdpdf/VLPU.pdf).

As you guessed: 330uF, 2.5V.

VLPU is the name of the product series.

3H5 is the datecode (couldn't find how to translate it).

Comment: The date code _could be_, **maybe**, the 4th week of august for one year that end with 3 (1993? 2003? 2013? I don't know...). I found this info [here](http://www.datamath.org/Datecodes.htm) but i don't have any other info about standard, meaning, etc (surely in IEC 60062 there's noting about this 3-character date code).